# Adding basic click animation to dynamic buttons

Tags: java, android

I have a simple button that looks like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:tag="general"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#343535"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".fragments.GeneralFragment">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/hello"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="@string/hello" />
```

Instead of static, these buttons should now be dynamic

```java
Button button = (Button) layout.getChildAt(0);
for(String text : readFromSharedPreferences) {
        // Set the layout
        Button btn = new Button(this.getContext());
        btn.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_TEXT_START);
        btn.setText(text);
        btn.setTag(text);
        btn.setLayoutParams(button.getLayoutParams());
        btn.setBackground(button.getBackground());
        layout.addView(btn);
```

The static button has an animation when I click on it. That looks like this:

[image]

But the dynamic button has no animation. So when I click on it, nothing happens. That looks like this:

[image]

How can I add this animation to my dynamic buttons?

### Update

I have figured out that my loop contains an on-touch listener. That looks like this:

```java
btn.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(getContext()) {
    // No code in here
});
```

If I remove that listener (even if it contains no code), the animation works great but I would like to keep it, because of my swipe function that is placed into it.

That is my whole code:

```java
// Swiping to link
btn.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(getContext()) {
    @Override
    public void onSwipeLeft() {
        super.onSwipeLeft();

        // Alert to ask
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
        builder.setTitle("Delete");
        builder.setMessage("Do you want to delete?");
        // Delete
        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", (dialog, which) -> {
            // Set the SharedPreferences as String
            ArrayList<String> currentSharedPreferences = readFromSharedPreferences(getContext());
            currentSharedPreferences.remove(btn.getTag().toString());
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String currentSharedPreferencesAsText = gson.toJson(currentSharedPreferences);

            // Update the SharedPreference k-text
            SharedPreferences mPrefs = getContext().getSharedPreferences("k-texts", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = mPrefs.edit();
            prefsEditor.putString("k-text", currentSharedPreferencesAsText);
            prefsEditor.apply();

            // Start the animation
            btn.animate()
                    .translationX(-btn.getWidth())
                    .alpha(0.0f)
                    .setDuration(300)
                    .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                            super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                            btn.clearAnimation();
                            btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            Snackbar.make(view, "Entry deleted.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("Delete", null).show();
                        }
                    });
        });
        // Cancel
        builder.setNegativeButton("No", (dialog, which) -> {
            // Silence is golden
        });

        builder.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick() {
        MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();
        Tts tts = new Tts(getContext(), _mediaPlayer, mainActivity.barTop, mainActivity.barBottom);
        try {
            tts.say(btn.getTag().toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

});
```

Well I could use

```java
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    return false;
}
```

Then the animation will work but `onClick()` wouldn't work anymore.

### Another update

I had a similar problem on another view. There my **static button** was not having a click effect. Then I have just simply added `android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"` and it worked! The same way I have just tried with my dynamic button. So I have added `btn.setForeground(button.getForeground());` but that doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Use MaterialButton instead of Button. MaterialButton is a subtype of Button that supports additional features. The Button that is in your XML layout is actually a MaterialButton if you're using a Material Components theme. The theme automatically swaps out Buttons for MaterialButtons when your XML is inflated. So, when dynamically creating buttons in your Java code, you must use MaterialButton if you want it to match the original.

Also, when using MaterialButton, never call `setBackground()` because this causes undefined behavior. It likely will prevent the ripple effect from occurring as well.

Alternatively, you can define your Button in its own XML file, even with the layout params it needs for LinearLayout. Then inflate the XML each time you need another button.

```
for(String text : readFromSharedPreferences) {
    Button btn = requireContext().getLayoutInflater()
        .inflate(R.layout.my_button, layout, true); // true adds it to layout
    btn.setText(text);
    btn.setTag(text);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have tried it with MaterialButton but I see no changes. Also, I have removed `setBackground()`. 
Since your code gives me some errors, I have tried it with `Button btn = (Button) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_general, layout, true);`. But also there I get the error: _android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.Button_. Also please tell me what `my_button` should be. `fragment_general` is just a fragment.

Comment: To inflate the XML button, the button needs to be by itself in its own XML file.

Comment: I have updated my question. Please check it again.